# Binding DependencyProperty to a usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I have created a dependency property but for some reason it seems to be failing, it must be sothing to do with the binding but I can't see what. The dependency property is as follows:

```
public class HighlightColour
{
    #region HighlightColour dependency property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty sm_ValueProperty;

    public static Color GetValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Color)obj.GetValue(sm_ValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetValue(DependencyObject obj, Color value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(sm_ValueProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    static HighlightColour()
    {
        var metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent);
        sm_ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Value",
                                                   typeof(Color),
                                                   typeof(HighlightColour), metadata);
    }
}
```

In the XAML I am trying to bind to this in a style template and set the background colour of a button:

```
<Style x:Key="CommonButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="custprop:HighlightColour.Value" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid Margin="0">
                    <Border Name="ButtonBody" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="12,12,12,12" />
                    <Border Name="Highlight" Opacity="0" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="12,12,12,12">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=(custprop:HighlightColour.Value), Source={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="HighlightAnim">
                                <Storyboard TargetName="Highlight" TargetProperty="Opacity" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.2" Duration="00:00:01"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="HighlightAnim"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For some reason it is failing and I see errors such as:

> Cannot get 'Value' value (type 'Color') from '' (type
>   'RelativeSource'). BindingExpression:Path=(0);
>   DataItem='RelativeSource' (HashCode=60828848); target element is
>   'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=10588721); target property is 'Color'
>   (type 'Color') InvalidCastException:'System.InvalidCastException:
>   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource' to
>   type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'.

Comment: Have just added the XAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=(custprop:HighlightColour.Value), 
                     Source={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
```

To:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=(custprop:HighlightColour.Value), 
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
```

For more information on Binding: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) or [this cheat sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Baboon unfortunately that didn't work, although the breakpoint in the constructor of HighlightColour now gets hit.

Comment: In the XAML I was trying to create a SolidcolourBrush using the colour in dependencyProperty so shouldn't the DependencyProperty be declared as a Color? The Error I gt now is: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Button', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=32830290); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

Comment: No you're right, I misread the XAML. It should be a Color indeed. Try removing the ".Value" from the Binding

Comment: With that I get a path error:System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '(custprop:HighlightColour)' property not found on 'object' ''Button' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=(custprop:HighlightColour); DataItem='Button' (Name=''); target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=13202999); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')
Do I have to set the DataContext to get this binding to work? I am not really sure what I would set it to.

Comment: Now it says it can't find your attached property on the Button. You're getting closer ;) Try binding to `HighlightColour` instead of `custprop:HighlightColour`

Comment: I just found out that adding a button to the main window and the style works correctly. However, having the style used by a user control in a separate library and the style doesn't work. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Is the style/attached property available in the separate library? (add reference etc)

Comment: My main window had a copy of the style and there was a separate copy of the style in the same library as the Usercontrol, at the time I wasn't sure how to import a style from another project. Since figuring out how to use Pack & import the style it is now working in both the main window and the UserControl. I don't understand what the problem was, but it works now. Many thanks for your help, it was much appreciated.

Comment: Once a property is attached, it behaves as if it was a regular property of a control. That's why you didn't need the `custprop:` prefix. If this solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't prefix with `sm_` or WPF won't be able to "find" your DP.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I just tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure only the suffix matters.